# How do I display products count in bigcommerce

Tags: count, bigcommerce

I want to display product count in my bigcommerce store, I am using Cornerstone theme
I have tried a few codes I had found in their support forums but they didn't work

{{category.total_products}}
{{category.count}}

I want it be written like this **Showing 1 - 17 of 200 results**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should get you what you are looking for (assuming there is pagination):

```
Showing {{pagination.category.start}} - {{pagination.category.end}} of {{category.total_products}} results
```